# What substance would crawl out of a vessel?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I remember in my first chemistry lessons at high school my teacher told us about atomic properties of materials elastics and stiffness and what ever else. At one point he came up with an example of a (theoretical?) liquid that would even crawl out of its vessel to overcome differences in gravity, *desiring* to get to as close to the gravity well as possible and even overcoming obstacles by trying to achieve this. Back then the idea quite fascinated me, enough to think about it again every few years.

But today, myself being a hobby astro physician and having at least a layman understanding of how gravity works, I start questioning his statement. I can't really understand how a substance could gain that "information" to when it can get closer to the source of gravity by a ratio between energy required to overcome the obstacle to gain in range reduction to the gravity source.

So my question is, what was the substance he was refering to?
Does such a substance exist? And if so, how does it work?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluid_helium-4 (don't know any more, so can't give you anything more than the link)

Comment: @orthocresol: Quite different in the reasons why it behaves like that from what my teacher back then explained, but in it self sounds like it could have been what he was referring to. Sad that you have not more specific knowledge about it.

Comment: I think @orthocresol pretty much answered your main question. Regarding the second part on how this happens beyond the wikipedia article, I'm afraid you need to dive deep into macroscopic quantum mechanics effects, and it's going to be a long reading, there are book chapters if not the entire books devoted to superfluids.

Comment: @andselisk: yeah definetly it answered my questions. But sadly I can't accept a comment as answer. Also as he mentioned that he can just give me the link and a link only answer would not be fine. Thats why I said that its sad.

Comment: Most liquids will move to a lower potential energy environment using the common device of the syphon.

Comment: @matt_black That means what?

Comment: You mean POLYOX? https://nnf.mit.edu/home/billboard/topic-4

Comment: @paracetamol: Interesting aswell :) But, no actually I'm quite sure it was helium-4, my teacher was referring to.

Comment: Liquids flow up a wall as long as the gain in interfacial energy (to the wall) can make up for the additional surface energy and gain of potential energy. If the substance is over the brink at the equillibrium height, it  leaks out. I fail to see what suprafluidity has to do with that, but perhaps someone else can put some light on it.

Comment: @Karl: Are you just nit picking on the fact that I didn't specify in the title that the vessel hast to be straightened up? Or is it, that some of my clarifications are ambiguous? Well my chemistry knowledge is very limited and I just tried to describe what my teacher years ago described, so sorry if I made any technical mistakes in my description. And otherwise, well it never occurred to me, that my soda crawled out of the drinking glass I poured it into. And if you try to tell me any liquid can mimic the properties of helium-4 tell me plz how to, I would love to experiment with that at home.

Comment: @Karl: Well by "crawling out" I didn't (and my teacher didn't said that back then either) meant that the fluid in question will just decimate a bit out of a beaker. I meant "crawling out" as in having an almost empty beaker after some time. The linked article reads like this is unique to that fluid. But if not so, I'm looking forward for such an answer. But anyways, how is that interfering with OP?

Comment: @Karl: Ah, haven't noticed that anyone referred to supra fluids in general. but except that, you are right... I'm not getting your point. But I hope possible answerers will. :D